# How to download image from a url in chrome app using chrome filesystem api?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-app

I have a url which has a image. I want to download that image using chrome api. I am developing a chrome app and not extension.
Can anyone please tell me where i am going wrong??

My code:

```
service('fileService', function($window){
    this.saveUserInfo = function(theFilePath) {
        // filepath is the url passed from controller{
        // Get the directory entry stored (if any).
        var fileUrl = "";
        var config = {
            type: 'saveFile',
            suggestedName: 'TheBee.png',
            accepts:[{extensions: ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']}]
        };

        chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry(config, function(writableEntry) {

            chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry(writableEntry, function(entry1) {

                entry1.getFile(theFilePath, {create:true}, function(entry2) {

                    entry2.createWriter(function(writer) {
                        var blob = new Blob({type: 'image/png'});
                        writer.write(blob);
                    });

                });

            });

        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Shouldn't the blob constructor take 2 arguments? `new Blob([data], {opts})`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var blob = new Blob({type: 'image/png'});
```

To

```
var blob = new Blob([entry1],{type: 'image/png'});
```

The Blob contructor acceptes blob parts: MSDN=> Blob(blobParts[, options])

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use getFile on entry1 because it is a file itself. You will need to change config.type to "openDirectory"

You also need to add an empty array as the first input to the blob constructor.

Comment: Can you please provide a plunker or something? I am very new to the chrome api. It would be really helpful if you can provide with plunker with same functionality..